# Ionic 3 API 28 and above issues

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic3

I am currently running an application using ionic 3, when running the app with targetSdkVersion = 27 and below I don't face any issue. But when I change targetSdkVersion to API 28 or API 29, I face few issues like double tap on input field to type in the login page. This only occurs at first time. After double tapping, normal touch is working. On top of that, when using Image picker, the image select cannot be read and the image is not displayed. Can anyone help me on why this issue is occurring only for Android API 28 and Android API 29 ?